# Preg match all img tags except the src with .gif extension

Tags: regex, wordpress, preg-match-all

I am customizing a plugin name post-script-responsive-images , where i want that this plugin should not re-size the images with `.gif` extension , because after re sizing `.gif` images , they looses their property of animation .

i read the plugin and found a `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$content, $result);
```

which is responsible for the getting all the image tags from the content area. But i want to exclude .gif extension.
How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/<img(?:(?!\.gif\b)[^>])+>/i
```

(not checking for source attribute, just if there's no `.gif` before the closing `>`)

[See test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kN7aP8/1); *sidenote:* regex is not the means for parsing html